# GeoServer 2.3.0 Proxy Setting

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, proxy

I've upgraded to GeoServer 2.3.0 running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.39 on my host WebFaction. My websites and GeoServer are on same host but different ports. How do I go about setting a proxy so that my site domain can grab data from GeoServer. I remember using a proxy.cgi with openlayers, but I'm now using Leaflet.

Is it possible to have my sites with domain capecodgis.com retrieve data from tomcat.capecodgis.com/geoserver.

I apologize in advance if I'm not clear. This is very confusing. I've been reading different docs and forums to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to make a XHR request to `tomcat.capecodgis.com/geoserver` from `capecodgis.com`, it will not be directly possible because this is a crossdomain request.

Generally speaking in the case of crossdomain, resources such as images, JavaScript files etc can be requested across domains. But for JavaScript to make a request to a service is not allowed.

This raises the question: What are you trying to do? If you are just trying to show a map using WMS, then it will work fine, since the JavaScript is just requesting Images. If you are requesting data from a service, (say from a WFS service, or a GetFeatureInfo request) then that will require a proxy.

Further more, looking at the [LeafLet API Docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html), it does not appear to support any functionality, which would require a proxy.

What I would do, is to create the website, and then test it using FireBug. If there was some request, which could not be sent due to crossdomain issues, you will see that as an error in FireBug's Console. I would then work only only that request.

Comment: thank you for the answer, at least now I know where to start.

Comment: I'm making a WFS request to return geojson data. I get an error in Firebug: SyntaxError: invalid label, which points to a valid geojson object. I cut and paste it into geojson lint and it's fine. So apparently the request works fine. In the Firebug console it says there was an error in transfer and it won't pass the data to the Leaflet function.

Comment: using the $.ajax error: function, I tried to pass it along to the Leaflet function anyways and it returned the error Invalid GeoJson object. Yet it is valid.